# ¿Qué es git-rerere y como funciona?

Tags: git, control-de-versiones

Según comprendí sirve para la sincronización de proyectos por medio de un guardado de la información de resolución de conflictos, pero no me queda del todo claro como utilizar y configurar el mismo.

Comment: Hola Carlos, ¿podrías poner un enlace al sitio donde obtuviste la información de ese comando? También, si es un caso práctico, cómo intentas ejecutarlo, qué resultado obtienes y cuál esperabas. Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

el comando "git-rerere" es una herramienta para ir guardando las resoluciones de conflictos de ramas que han divergido de la principal hace mucho tiempo.

El problema real es que cuando intentas hacer un rebase de una rama contra master por ejemplo y tu rama esta detrás de master por muchos commits es posible que te toque arreglar el mismo conflicto una y otra vez, es acá donde "git-rerere" juego a favor de nosotros, al ir guardando las resoluciones que vamos haciendo al final podrá realizar un automerge quitándonos la esta tediosa tarea.

Todo el detalle de esta función la podrás encontrar muy detallada en la documentación oficial de git:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Por cierto, para usarlo hay que activarlo y el resto lo hace git:

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

Saludos,